# Update multiple values at once in Laravel using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have database table structure like:

```
   id       | column1 |  column2 | column n 

rowid1  -         -         -        -
rowid2  -         -         -        -
rowidn  -         -         -        -
```

Now i have multiple id and column names i want to update row with id using some sort of batch operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eloquent to update multiple rows at once, either using a model or otherwise. For example:

```
Model::where($conditions)->update($newValues);
```

or

```
DB::table('users')->where($conditions)->update($newValues);
```

I would suggest taking a look at the Laravel documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will sequence of id and its new values be same

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you wanted to update a series of rowIds, you could say, `Model::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->update(['column1' => $newValue]);`

Comment: I have multiple id and associated values with each id, will the above work in that case to update in batch

Comment: Yes, just change the ids in `[1, 2, 3]` to whatever the ids are that you want to update, and then put the column names and new values in the second array (based on the code I've put in my previous comment)